# SwiftUI list allow reordering ONLY when edit button is pressed

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to enable reordering of List elements in SwiftUI List ONLY when `EditButton()` in the toolbar is pressed, not otherwise. I tried something like this

```
@Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode

var editAllowed: Bool { editMode?.wrappedValue == .active }
```

And then on the list, this modifier:

```
.onMove(perform: editMode == .active ? { from, to in
    //Do reordering on data model
} : nil)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this simple approach using a Bool and simultaneousGesture, to `...allow reordering ONLY when edit button is pressed`

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDisabled = true  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<10) { Text("\($0)") }
                    .onMove { _, _ in  }
                    .moveDisabled(isDisabled)  // <--- here
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
                    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                        isDisabled.toggle()  // <--- here
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the move modifier with:

```
.moveDisabled(condition)
```

Toggle a variable in the edit button and pass it as the parameter of the `moveDisabled`.

The `condition` can be also an observing variable like:

```
@Environment(\.editMode) var editMode
var moveDisabled: Bool { editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing != true }
```

It should be after `.onMove` to control the whole list:

```
List {
    ForEach(1..<10) { Text("\($0)") }
        .onMove { _, _ in  }
        .moveDisabled(condition)
}
```

<sub>⚠️ note that from iOS 14, `editMode` only changes for the child views when you use `EditButton`!. So you should observe in the child or pass the environment from the child to the parent!</sub>

Comment: Does this work on List as a whole or individual row elements? And what condition should I use to trigger it? Also, how do I intercept EditButton action?

Comment: The whole as you asked, prevents the default long press

Comment: How to intercept edit button action? In other words, how do I toggle a variable in Edit button as you say?

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: No need to intercept, just observe

Comment: It doesn't work as I said. Please write the exact condition to check, exactly where and how to toggle a var.

Comment: @DeepakSharma `.moveDisabled(editMode?.wrappedValue != .active)` works for me.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini It doesn't work for me, tapping Edit button does not bring reordering controls in the list the moment I add your line in the code.